# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x.... нарушение прав доступа при записи по 0x,,,, fscanf_s()

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Возникает исключение при отладке когда исполняется функция fscanf_s

```
char lineHeader[128];
int res = fscanf_s(input, "%s", lineHeader);
```

файл октрывается корректно (это проверяется)

```
FILE * input = NULL;
fopen_s(&input, path, "r");
```

память для %s как видите тоже выделена
но при отладке на строке с *fscanf* перебрасывает в библиотеку stdio.h и вызывается исключение вот здесь

```
return __stdio_common_vfscanf(
            _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_SCANF_OPTIONS | _CRT_INTERNAL_SCANF_SECURECRT,
            _Stream, _Format, _Locale, _ArgList);
```

название исключения в названии вопроса.
Подскажите в чем ошибка изза которой оно не работает.

Comment: 4м параметром добавьте длину вашего массива. И попробуйте снова.

Comment: Читайте документацию к `fscanf_s`.

Comment: @こきん спасибо помогло, напиши ответом на вопрос я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо добавить 4ым параметром длину массива